# OpenID Connect Token endpoint returning a bad request

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, onelogin

I am using OneLogin OpenID Connect, I did the initial redirect to OpenID server, put username and password in and OneLogin redirected me to the callback url I provided. I have received a "Code" from this and would like to exchange this code for turning it into an access_token.

I am trying to make a request to the token endpoint but it is returning a 400 Bad Request with this error:

"error_description": "invalid authorization header value format"

I have attached a screenshot below. I didn't have "Client_Secret" in the Authorization header before, I looked around and tried it with "Basic" as well. But none of it seems to work.

Can anyone help me with some insight?

I was also following these two tutorials:
https://openidconnect.net

https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/connect-to-onelogin

I have looked on here to see if I was doing anything wrong. But I still get the same error.
https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect#token-endpoint

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Authorization header has an incorrect format, it should look like the example below for the username "username" and the password "password".

*Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=*

The variable **dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=** is found by concatenating username and password with a colon as separator (*username:password*) and calculating the [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) value of this new string (*dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=*).

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization) does that for you, just click on the Authorization tab next to Headers. You'll probably need Basic Auth.